# OpenCV qr code detection dependent on image size

Tags: python, image, qr-code, opencv

I am using `cv2.QRCodeDetector` to decode QR codes in images. I have noticed that the size of the image matters for the decoding. For example, save this image: https://i.ibb.co/QKF3wQ7/cropped.jpg (it should be of size 640x356)

Now if you do the following:

```
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
img = cv2.imread('cropped.jpg')
# img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.2, fy=0.2)
decoded, points, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
print('Decoded text is: ', decoded)
```

Output:

```
Decoded text is:
```

But if you decrease the size of the image (by uncommenting the third line):

```
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
img = cv2.imread('cropped.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.2, fy=0.2)
decoded, points, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
print('Decoded text is: ', decoded)
```

Output:

```
Decoded text is:  BMLF000117*0000000000007883*2021-05-27*11:15:43*43.92
```

I would like to be able to read QR codes without worrying about the size of the image. How can I know what is a good size? I found that it depends on the original size of the image, whether the image is rotated left or right, or unrotated. But in general, I can't know what resizing will be appropriate in order for the decoder to decode.

What can I do in order to decode the QR code?

Comment: Can't reproduce, and I've tried 5 different OpenCV releases. Using your sample image, it doesn't detect anything no matter what the scale.

Comment: OK, it looks like the picture was too tightly cropped for the 0.2 scale variant to be recognised. I can get it to work with the original scale image if I first run an Otsu threshold and then erode the result with a 3x3 cross element.

Comment: I didn't understand the approach. If you could elaborate or give an answer, I would be grateful. Strange that you can't reproduce, when you download the image, what size it is?

Comment: Hello, Dan, Can you please further explain? I need it urgently :)

Comment: Hello, Dan, I would be grateful if you have time to help me! :)